# How to deserialize a JSON object with ":" in a property name in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I have this object value that is being returned and I would like to convert it into a useful JSON object that I can inspect and manipulate. Ultimately, my goal is to validate the values of `username` and `accessKey`. 
But 2 things are throwing me off. Double `{{` makes it invalid JSON and `sauce:options` can't be converted into a property in a class because I can't create a class with a property called `sauce:options`.

```
{{
  "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
  "browserVersion": "latest",
  "platformName": "Windows 10",
  "sauce:options": {
    "username": "test",
    "accessKey": "123"
  }
}}
```

Here is what I tried:

`string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions);`

`SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions` returns that object I mentioned above.

Got this back: **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from 'BinaryLocation' on 'OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions'.'**

I also tried this:

`var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SauceSession.Options.ConfiguredEdgeOptions);`

And got back this **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from 'BinaryLocation' on 'OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeOptions'.'**

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You've edited your original question and it has entered the reopen queue. Wait until the process completes.

Comment: Oh, sorry :( I saw it was closed and I was told to ask a new question. I'll close this one